# BigQuery, disable Streaming Buffer

Tags: c#, google-bigquery

I'm using .Net Client Library to use BigQuery and I'm running in the issue *"UPDATE or DELETE statement over table ... would affect rows in the streaming buffer, which is not supported"*

I understand the use of streaming buffer, I know that I need to wait to UPDATE or DELETE, and the response is the expected behavior, but I don't really need it, because I have a process where the user creates a register in DB with a status (0 in example) and after a few minutes, after the user do some things, that status change and I need to update it in DB register (created a few minutes ago).

I need a workaround for this. Avoid or disable streaming buffer if it's possible, but I cannot figure out how achieve this.

Comment: it's ill-advice, but BigQuery is not a good place for operative data.
use it as events storing and then build views (in BigQuery) to display aggregated from events data from different tables.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround that I have found is this. Use `UploadJson` method. With this I need to wait to the whole data be inserted, but it's fine for me, also I can upload a larger quantity of data in one request.

```
    private bool UploadJson(BigQueryTable table, IEnumerable<string> jsons)
    {
        try
        {
            var job = table.UploadJson(jsons);
            BigQueryJob result = job.PollUntilCompleted();
            if (result.Status.Errors?.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (ErrorProto error in result.Status.Errors)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(error.Message);
                }

                result.ThrowOnAnyError();
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

        return false;
    }
```